pyautogui locateCenterOnScreen is not finding my source image or 'needle'
I am searching in an area of 543 pixels wide and 378 pixels height from the top left corner of my screen for the following 'needle'

You may recognise the Firefox logo.
My search area looks like this:

I am using the following code:
import pyautogui
import time

search_region = (0,0,543,378)
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('graphics/firefox_icon.png',grayscale=True,confidence = 0.4,region=search_region)
print("We found it at X:"+str(x)+" Y:"+str(y))
pyautogui.click(x, y)

When executing the code using a confidence value of 1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5 it raises an ImageNotFoundException. When using confidence of 0.4 it usually selects a pixel just under the finder menu which is in the clouds(coords X:80, Y:69). The same happens for grayscale=True or False. This is my challenge, I cannot get a simple use case like this to work - and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please offer some options I can try to fix my code or my configuration. As a note - I am using Macs 'Shift - Cmd - 4' short cut to select the area to create my needle image - which is output as a png by default, incase that is perhaps related.
My environment:

Python version: 3.12.4
pyautolib version: 0.9.54
opencv-python version: 4.10.0.84
Mac OS version: 14.5
MacBook Pro M1(retina display) in dual monitor mode with a 34" widescreen


you can try lackey instead of pyautogui, specifaclly lackey.wait for searching the icon.

You shouldn't use grayscale=True not an issue for your example but the color is usually the main thing that enables the match and its always better enabled. Also confidence=0.4 is too low you need 0.8 at least or more if there are similar things on screen. 0.4 basically means it can locate anything and say its your icon.  Finally in this type of applications pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen or lackey.wait frequently can't find the given image on screen so you shoul make it search more than once. lackey does this automatically, for pyautogui try minSearchTime=5 or write a loop yourself.

I tried passing minSearchTime=5 in as an argument to locateCenterOnScreen, and it still fails to find it. I also took greyScale=True off, which made no difference. The stack message when the exception occurs with the minSearchTime argument is different and highlights :     raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image (highest confidence = 0.482) suggesting 0.482 was the highest confidence found....anything else I can try? I am not sure what this feature is for when it cannot locate a strongly differentiated image in a space

I actually used it many times it works fine and in your case it definetly should find since object is quite obvious. Let me ask why do you specify a search region why not search it on the whole screen ? Can you also try lackey.wait('graphics/firefox_icon.png',30) followed by lackey.click('graphics/firefox_icon.png')

Running Lackey results in ValueError: ("Key 'c' is not mapped to any known key.", ValueError('Unrecognized character: c')) which makes little sense to me considering I'm not interacting with the keyboard on those 2 lines as you suggest? I am not searching the whole screen as my use case wants to be relatively performant, and why search the whole screen when I know where my region of searching is, and that matters?

If you are sure that the icon is in the region always, then its perfectly fine. The issue you have with the lackey seems to be a common issue for non-english keyboard users with keys like 'shift', 'tab', 'ctrl' etc. however i see that error with key 'c' for the first time. I dont have the exact solution but the cause is this line keyboard.add_hotkey("alt+shift+c", _abort_script, suppress=True) in the init file of lackey which calls this function from keyboard key_to_scan_codes(key, error_if_missing=True) many times and for different keys and your program gives the error for key='c'.

You can comment out the line in lackey init.py file to try if it can find the icon on the screen, or you can directly use cv2.matcTemplate to see if the issue is in the locating image or not and i believe thats the extent of my knowledge.

@BarışAktaş how do I comment out that line?

"C:\Users\msi-nb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39.zip\Python39\Lib\site-packages\lackey" this is the file locaiton on my python environment after you find your python.exe file relative path must be similar. In this folder, in the __init__.py file line 50 is keyboard.add_hotkey("alt+shift+c", _abort_script, suppress=True) just put a "#" at the start of the line or you can even delete it.  Note that this is not a solution to your "ValueError: ("Key 'c' is not mapped to any known key." error, but not a problem either if you dont use lackey's keyboard related functions .

I see that you are on Mac OS. Mac OS commonly runs on systems with very high DPI displays. The system applies a blanket 2x scaling to everything, which may interfere here.
For the "locate" function to work, the template must be the same scale as the haystack. The function does not support multi-scale search. Your template appears to satisfy this, so that is probably not the issue.
pyautogui, or the version you are using, might still have bugs related to Mac OS scaling, in that the template is found at half the coordinates you expect it to, or the involved APIs somehow access a double/half-resolution haystack.
Here's an issue with pyautogui that looks resolved in recent versions: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/589

okay that's starting to look like a potential cause for the issue. Are you suggesting that the needle is not the same scale? Because it is taken with the print screen function - why would it not be the same scale. How can I verify the scale?

I just checked, your template and haystack appear to have the same scale. you're on Mac OS, right? those systems commonly have extra high DPI displays, so things might be 2x scaled in ways I am unfamiliar with. I see plenty evidence online that people have issues with that. you might just want to file an issue and let the developers of the library figure it out.

Indeed I am using MacOS and had been reading about issues but they are not similar. Issue 589 is associated to incorrect pixel locations...but the detection of the needle is working as designed it seems. For me the problem is different as the needle simply isn't found at all. I have made an issue here and it's not been responded to...https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/878

try scaling the template by 2x or 0.5x and see if that works better (try cv.pyrUp/cv.pyrDown). if it does, you fixed their bug for them.

How do I scale the template? Is there a simple programmatic way to do that?

try cv.pyrUp/cv.pyrDown

I may be wrong but that appears to loose resolution during the pyrDown which I think is the direction we would want to go...doesn't that mean that we loose distinction in the needle and therefore lower further the likelihood of finding the needle. I'll give this a go - but doubt it would work :  src = cv.pyrDown(src, dstsize=(cols // 2, rows // 2)) I believe that would shrink the needle by a half, or factor of 2? Agreed @christoph?

Okay shrinking by factor of 2 as you advice worked but only if I put the confidence to 0.6, and it's slooow. Lackey seems fiddly, I am surprised it's this hard to do realtime relatively quick recognition!

try scaling up then. "confidence" of 0.6 is way too low to make sense. that should be a lot higher. if all of that isn't it, perhaps pyautogui doesn't know what order of color channels to use. try a cvtColor() with COLOR_BGR2RGB on the template
